# Is being defiled from consuming unclean meats a physical defilement or spiritual defilement?

Tags: holy

Reference Leviticus 11 and Deuteronomy 14.
Is there any distinction of defilement or are there specific types of defilement (e.g. ceremonial)?

Comment: The Torah makes no such distinction and thus, all defilement is spiritual.

Comment: @Dottard I can't agree. Whether ceremonial defilement it is spiritual or not is debatable,  but since it involves no violation of a moral commandment, no guilt results from it. That is a major distinction. Even [utensils can become defiled](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/9266-kelim)... can that be a spiritual state?

Comment: @DanFefferman - the defilement is only relevant when used by a person.  Defiled things do not matter unless it comes into contact with a person.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree then.

Answer (score 1):

It is spiritual, and requires a spiritual remedy. The reason is that it involves disobedience, and is a type of sin. However, there is indeed a distinction between ceremonial uncleanness and sin.

Examples of ceremonial uncleanness:

- giving birth (Leviticus 12:2)
- having sex with one's wife (Leviticus 15:18)
- menstruating, or coming in contact with a menstruous woman (Leviticus 15:33)
- touching or carrying unclean animals/insects (Leviticus 11:24)
- having certain skin diseases (Leviticus 11:24)

**So, becoming defiled by eating unclean meats is a spiritual state, a sin - because in virtually all cases the person has chosen to disobey a commandment. It is not the meat that defiles, but the act of eating it. On the other hand, ritual defilement is not a sin in itself. Indeed sometimes it results from natural states (such as menstruation) or even blessed acts (such as procreation).**

---

**Addendum**: This answer may raise the question of why Jesus said "not what goes into a man's mouth defiles a man." That particular issue was not about unclean meats. It was about eating with unwashed hands, a requirement for priests but not for common people. By Jesus' time a tradition had developed where by some teachers of the Law required it for laypeople as well as priests, to avoid eating with ritually defiled hands. Jesus took the opposite side of this particular debate. (Matthew 15:11) But he did not teach his disciples to eat unclean meats.

Comment: According to the Talmud, the requirement for hand washing for **priests** or ones that eat Taharot, started at the time of King Solomon. But when it was extended to all laypeople, I do not know. Do you have a source that it started in the days of Jesus? It could be extended after the destruction of the first temple, or at the time of Ezrah, or during the second temple period much before Jesus.

Comment: What distinguishes touching unclean carcass to be ceremonially unclean as compared to eating unclean animal? Is it safe to say that any defilement that mentions an ending time period (e.g. "until the even") is ceremonial uncleanness?

Comment: @O.J. either specify a time or way to cleanse/purify. This verse does not mention how to get purified.

Comment: @Kapandaria - The Talmud includes many books with varying rabbinical traditions. Acc. to the [Jewish Encyclopedia](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14577-uncleanness),  "in the Mishnaic time [the earliest part of the Talmud] 'only the ablution after the meal is spoken of by the Hillelites and Shammaites (Ber. iii. 1)." These were the two leading Pharisaic schools. The  tradition to wash before a meal probably started to gain popularity at the time the gospels were written, but some teachers may have insisted on it earlier. In any case it was a "live issue" in Jesus day, not settled law.

Comment: @DanFefferman actually I found out that it  probably happened little time before Jesus, in the roof top of khananiah son of Hezekiah son of Gurion, when the Shammaites out numbered the Hillelites,